# Почему exec() не исполняет с .php

Tags: php, exec

Четно пытаюсь запустить асинхронно file.php из one.php, да еще так, чтобы передать параметр $user_id. Но этот запрос не работает:

```
exec("file.php $user_id > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

Хотя даже вот так `exec("file.php")` не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

PS: file.php и one.php находятся в одной директории (не корень), а хостер говорит, что функция включена..

Comment: *file.php и one.php находятся в одной директории (не корень)* - а это никак не гарантирует, что ос будет искать file.php в той же директории, вычисляйте и используйте абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что причина в том, что php - это не программа. Нужно вызывать интерпретатор php, передав ему в качестве аргумента имя файла со скриптом.

Comment: Точно, это же консоль!